# Objective C: Scrolling multiple XIB

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am making an interactive magazine app and i made different XIBs for each page.

how will i able to switch pages(different XIBs) on swipe?
Is it possible to have a scrolling XIBs?

Before, i used UIScrollView that has one XIB and the paging is working fine, but i'm having issues with applying the touch events and gestures on it.

Comment: @Dimme UIScrollView,i've tried it and it's working well for paging like what i've said on the post, but i'm having issues with applying events on the pages. like, when i applied the drag and drop function it's not working but when i tried it without UIScrollView it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dimme i would recommend you to load your another views modally throughout a method that recognize gesture like:

```
- (void)doGestureAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    /* load your another view here */

    yourAnotherViewController *controller = [[yourAnotherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourAnotherViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

You can change the way the transition to the another view its animated setting the variable controller.modalTransitionStyle: to this available options

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```